# Cómo agregar una excepción Try y Catch para evitar que ingresen caracteres

Tags: java, excepciones

Tengo un proyecto de una calculadora con interfaz gráfica, la cual es muy básica. El problema me surge cuando algún usuario introduce alguna letra o cadena de caracteres, lo que necesito es agregar una excepción con `try` y `catch` que mande un mensaje al usuario indicando que solo se permiten números. No he podido agregar la excepción porque no entiendo muy bien como funcionan y en dónde puedo agregarlas en mi código. Si me pudiesen ayudar.

Les adjunto mi código:

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class Calculadora extends JFrame {

    private JPanel pnlContenido;
    private JTextField txtDato_1;
    private JTextField txtDato_2;
    private JTextField txtResultado;
    private Double Resultado = 0.0, Dato_1 = 0.0, Dato_2 = 0.0;
    private String strDouble = " ";

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Calculadora frame = new Calculadora();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public Calculadora() {
        setResizable(false);
            setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(Calculadora.class.getResource("/imagenes/calc.png")));
        setTitle("Calculadora_basica");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 470, 215);
        pnlContenido = new JPanel();
        pnlContenido.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(pnlContenido);
        pnlContenido.setLayout(null);

        JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Dato_1:");
        lblNewLabel.setBounds(21, 40, 56, 14);
        pnlContenido.add(lblNewLabel);

        txtDato_1 = new JTextField();
        txtDato_1.setBounds(87, 38, 86, 20);
        pnlContenido.add(txtDato_1);
        txtDato_1.setColumns(10);

        JLabel lblDato_2 = new JLabel("Dato_2:");
        lblDato_2.setBounds(21, 80, 56, 14);
        pnlContenido.add(lblDato_2);

        txtDato_2 = new JTextField();
        txtDato_2.setBounds(87, 77, 86, 20);
        pnlContenido.add(txtDato_2);
        txtDato_2.setColumns(10);

        JLabel lblResultado = new JLabel("Resultado:");
        lblResultado.setBounds(21, 122, 143, 14);
        pnlContenido.add(lblResultado);

        txtResultado = new JTextField();
        txtResultado.setEnabled(false);
        txtResultado.setBounds(85, 119, 110, 20);
        pnlContenido.add(txtResultado);
        txtResultado.setColumns(10);

        JButton btnSuma = new JButton("Suma");
        btnSuma.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
                if(txtDato_2.getText().equals("")) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Intriduce valores en ambas cajas ", "Error al realizar la Suma", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                }
                else if (txtDato_1.getText().equals("")) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Intriduce valores en ambas cajas ", "Error al realizar la Suma", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                }
                else {
                    Dato_1 = Double.parseDouble(txtDato_1.getText());
                    Dato_2 = Double.parseDouble(txtDato_2.getText());
                    Resultado = Dato_1 + Dato_2;
                    strDouble = String.format("%.3f", Resultado);
                    txtResultado.setText("" + strDouble);
                }
            }
        });
        btnSuma.setIcon(new ImageIcon(Calculadora.class.getResource("/imagenes/j.png")));
        btnSuma.setBounds(268, 17, 162, 30);
        pnlContenido.add(btnSuma);

        JButton btnResta = new JButton("Resta");
        btnResta.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
                if (txtDato_1.getText().equals("")&&txtDato_2.getText().equals("")) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Intriduce valores en ambas cajas", "Error al realizar la Resta", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                }
                else if (txtDato_1.getText().equals("")) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Intriduce valores en ambas cajas ", "Error al realizar la Resta", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                }
                else {
                    Dato_1 = Double.parseDouble(txtDato_1.getText());
                    Dato_2 = Double.parseDouble(txtDato_2.getText());
                    Resultado = Dato_1-Dato_2;
                    strDouble = String.format("%.3f", Resultado);
                    txtResultado.setText("" + strDouble);
                }
            }
        });
        btnResta.setIcon(new ImageIcon(Calculadora.class.getResource("/imagenes/j.png")));
        btnResta.setBounds(268, 55, 162, 30);
        pnlContenido.add(btnResta);

        JButton btnMultiplicacion = new JButton("Multiplicacion");
        btnMultiplicacion.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
                if (txtDato_1.getText().equals("")&&txtDato_2.getText().equals("")) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Intriduce valores en ambas cajas", "Error al realizar la Multiplicacion", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                }
                else if (txtDato_1.getText().equals("")) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Intriduce valores en ambas cajas ", "Error al realizar la Multiplicacion", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                }
                else {
                    Dato_1 = Double.parseDouble(txtDato_1.getText());
                    Dato_2 = Double.parseDouble(txtDato_2.getText());
                    Resultado = Dato_1*Dato_2;
                    strDouble = String.format("%.3f", Resultado);
                    txtResultado.setText("" + strDouble);
                }
            }
        });
        btnMultiplicacion.setIcon(new ImageIcon(Calculadora.class.getResource("/imagenes/j.png")));
        btnMultiplicacion.setBounds(268, 93, 162, 30);
        pnlContenido.add(btnMultiplicacion);

        JButton btnDivi = new JButton("Divicion");
        btnDivi.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
                if (txtDato_1.getText().equals("")&&txtDato_2.getText().equals("")) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Intriduce valores en ambas cajas", "Error al realizar la Divicion", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                }   
                else if (txtDato_1.getText().equals("")) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Intriduce valores en ambas cajas ", "Error al realizar la Divicion", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                }
                else {
                    Dato_1 = Double.parseDouble(txtDato_1.getText());
                    Dato_2 = Double.parseDouble(txtDato_2.getText());
                    Resultado = Dato_1/Dato_2;
                    strDouble = String.format("%.3f", Resultado);
                    txtResultado.setText("" + strDouble);
                }
            }
        });
        btnDivi.setIcon(new ImageIcon(Calculadora.class.getResource("/imagenes/j.png")));
        btnDivi.setBounds(268, 129, 162, 30);
        pnlContenido.add(btnDivi);
    }
}
```

Nota: estoy aprendiendo apenas a programar en java, si me lo pudieran explicar se los agradecería bastante.

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar solo el **código relevante**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

podes crear un método que devuelva true si es un numero o false si es carácter. Te dejo como seria el método:

```
    private static boolean esNumeroInteger(String cadena)
        {
            try //intenta convertir la cadena a entero y si no puede captura la excepción
            {
                Integer.parseInt(cadena);
                return true;
            } 
            catch (NumberFormatException nfe)//aca atrapas la excepcion
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

En vez de utilizar `NumberFormatException nfe`, podrías utilizar `Exception ex` para capturar cualquier excepción. Como yo se que tipo de excepción puede saltar uso la especifica, pero si no sabes que tipo de excepción puede venir, usa `Exception`.

Answer (score 0):

Aunque el `NumberFormatException` podría ser una buena solución, sería mejor proteger el programa haciendo que los `JTextField` sólo admitan números. Yo usaría ambas cosas para asegurarme.

Te paso el siguiente enlace que explica como hacer que un `JTextField` sólo admita números, espero que te sirva.

http://chuwiki.chuidiang.org/index.php?title=JTextField_que_solo_admite_digitos

Answer (score 0):

Hola Puedes usar esta libreria org.apache.commons.lang

Tiene una clase llamada StringUtils.

en StringUtils llamas a isNumeric

te quedaria algo asi:

```
if(isNumeric(txtDato_2)){
    //Realizas la operacion
} else {
    //Lanzas algun mensaje o alerta o simplemente eliminas el string 
     ingresado etc.
}
```

Saludos.